# DELETE request to Nancy from HTML

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, nancy

I have a REST API implemented in [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org). I use DELETE for the following endpoint:

```
Delete ["/usermanagement/{id}"] = parameters => {
            repo.DeleteUser(parameters.id);
            return Response.AsRedirect("/usermanagement");
        };
```

I wanna call this end point from my simple html page. So far I came up with this solution:

```
<button type="button" onclick="deleteUserWithID('@Current.ID')">Delete</button></td>
```

and JS:

```
<script>
    function deleteUserWithID( ID ){
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open( 'DELETE', 'usermanagement/' + ID, false );
      xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'text/html' );
      xhr.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

This works, as far as hitting a endpoint, doing the business logic. The problem is that doesn't return to `AsRedirect("/usermanagement");` ie.: it doesn't reload the page. I have tried to execute this endpoint from POSTMAN directly without any of the above JS, and I got back the expected html (`/usermanagement`) page.

Has anyone experienced similar problem? What could be possibly wrong with the above JS that it causes Nancy NOT to return `/usermanagement` page when executed from browser (returning this page when executed via POSTMAN)? I tried it several browsers, with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser redirects do not work like that with AJAX (Ie, `XMLHttpRequest`).  If you check the `xhr.responseText` property, I think you will find that it contains the HTML for the `/usermanagement` page.  But, if you want to actually redirect the browser to that page, you should do so via JavaScript:

```
function deleteUserWithID( ID ){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open( 'DELETE', 'usermanagement/' + ID, true );
  xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'text/html' );
  xhr.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
  xhr.send(null);
}
function handleResponse(e) {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      location.href = "/usermanagement";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ChristianHorsdal - `XMLHttpRequest` will follow redirects, so the final status code will be a 200.